Pseudometric is continuous
Fix two metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ and $f: X \to Y$ a continuous map. For two points $x,y \in X$, we call a sequence of points $x=x_0,\dots, x_n=y$ $\varepsilon$-chain ($\epsilon>0$)from $x$ to $y$ if $d_X(x_{i-1},x_i) \leq \varepsilon$ for all $i$. We define now the pseudo-metric
$$\mathrm{p}_{\varepsilon}(x,y):=\inf \Biggl\{ \sum^n_{i=1}d_Y(f(x_{i-1}),f(x_i))\Biggl\},$$
where the infimum is taken along all $\varepsilon$-chains from $x$ to $y$.
My question is now if for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, this function is continuous?

If $x’$ is close to $x$ and $y’$ is close to $y$ there is an obvious to produce an $\epsilon$-chain from $x’$ to $y’$ out of an $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $y$. And vice versa.

and therefore it should be continuous?

Yes, since by the continuity of $f$ you can also guarantee that the sum $\sum^n_{i=1}d_Y(f(x_{i-1}),f(x_i))$ for the two chains is close.

but what about the infimum? This is not obvious for me..

I think it works if $f$ is uniformly continuous, but if $f$ is just continuous, I have my doubts.

Why it works when $f$ is uniformly continuous?

I can write an answer to this effect, if you want? I'm not 100% certain it works until I actually write it up, but I believe Jonathan Hole's suggestion is essentially sound when $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I'm just going to denote $p_{\varepsilon}$ by $p$ for brevity.
Fix $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ and $(a, b) \in X \times X$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists some $\delta_0 > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
d_X(x, a) < \delta_0 &\implies d_Y(f(x), f(a)) < \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} \tag{1} \\
d_X(y, b) < \delta_0 &\implies d_Y(f(y), f(b)) < \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
We can assume without loss of generality that $\delta_0 \le \varepsilon$.
Let us suppose that we have such $x$ and $y$, so that the left hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold. I claim that $|p(x, y) - p(a, b)| \le \varepsilon_0$, which will prove the continuity of $p$.
Now, suppose $\varepsilon_1 > 0$. By the definition of $p$, we know there must exist an $\varepsilon$-chain $a_0=a, a_1, \ldots, a_n = b$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n d_Y(f(a_i), f(a_{i-1})) < p(a, b) + \varepsilon_1.$$
Since $d((a, b), (c, d)) < \delta_0 \le \varepsilon$, we have $d_X(a, x) < \varepsilon$ and $d_X(b, y) < \varepsilon$. As such, if we let $a_{-1} = x$ and $a_{n+1} = y$, then $a_{-1}, a_0, \ldots, a_{n+1}$ is an $\varepsilon$-chain from $x$ to $y$. We therefore have
\begin{align*}
p(x, y) &\le \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} d_Y(f(a_{i-1}), f(a_i)) \\
&= d_Y(f(x), f(a)) + d_Y(f(b), f(y)) + \sum_{i=1}^n d_Y(f(a_{i-1}), f(a_i)) \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} + p(a, b) + \varepsilon_1 \\
&= p(a, b) + \varepsilon_0 + \varepsilon_1.
\end{align*}
This holds for any $\varepsilon_1 > 0$, so
$$p(x, y) \le p(a, b) + \varepsilon_0.$$
The above relies on $(1)$ and $(2)$ holding, for our particular $x$ and $y$. We can therefore apply the same argument, exchanging $(a, b)$ for $(x, y)$. This tells us that
$$|p(a, b) - p(x, y)| \le \varepsilon_0,$$
which completes the proof: $p$ is continuous at $(a, b)$.

I think you only need continuity of $f$ to guarantee that $p$ is continuous.

@JonathanHole You're right. Thank you.
